# Se puede mostrar una opcion de pantalla completa en una web?

Tags: javascript, html5

Así como con los vídeos y su etiqueta html le permite a los vídeos ampliarse a pantalla completa, me preguntaba si existe la opción en html o javascript de poner en pantalla completa una página web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elegís el elemento a mostrar en pantalla completa, en este caso todo el documento

Tener en cuenta, que solo se puede poner en pantalla completa por una acción del usuario, por ejemplo un click en un botón.

```
var elem = document.documentElement;

/* Abrir en fullscreen */
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

/* Cerrar fullscreen */
function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. impecable.

Answer (score 3):

Elegis el elemento a mostrar pantalla completa. Y tienes que poner pantalla completa cuando el usuario haya echo una accion.

```
var elem = document.querySelector("element")
elem.requestFullscreen = elem.requestFullscreen || elem.webkitRequestFullscreen || elem.msRequestFullscreen;
document.exitFullscreen = document.exitFullscreen || document.webkitExitFullscreen || document.msExitFullscreen;

 function fullscreen(){
         elem.requestFullscreen()
 }
  function closefullscreen(){
     document.exitFullscreen()
   }
```

Comment: muchas gracias. impecable